# How do I insert a row into a DataGridView programmatically?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to insert a row into a DataGridView programmatically. The columns are:

> Column1 combobox
>
> Column2 textbox

This is my code. Column1 is bound to a table using the built-in DataSource of DataGridView.

```
DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
DataGridViewComboBoxCell __action1 = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
DataGridViewTextBoxCell __site = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();

__action.Value = 1; //1 is id.
__sitetype.Value = "google.com";
```

but this gives me an error of "DataGridViewComboBoxCell invalid value." How do I fix this?

Comment: Is your `DataGridView` **bound** to a data source? If so, you add rows to the data source, not to the control.

Comment: only the combobox is bound to data source, so that it can populate list, the text column is to be set from code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DataGridViewRow dr = new DataGridViewRow();
DataGridViewCell dcDescription = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();

dcDescription.Value = "some text";

dr.Cells.Add(dcDescription);
dataGridViewDoctorEventsAddServices.Rows.Add(dr);
```

Comment: need to set the combobox value also, how to do that?

Comment: Yes, you should set each control before you add it.